# What is wrong with my python GCD and LCM checker?

Tags: python

My code does not work. Please help me correct my code:

```
import math
a,b = input().split()
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
print((int(math.gcd(a,b))),(int((a*b)/(math.gcd(a,b)))))
```

Comment: Please clearly mention the error.

Comment: Please be more specific than "does not work". Added some inputs and expected outputs that you are having an issue with and tell us why.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think it is because you are using too much `datatype conversion` (like you can take input in `int` format instead of `splitting and datatype conversion`) and another reason is you can store the `GCD` value in one variable so that you can reuse that value for calculating `LCM`.

But if you want to calculate `GCD` and `LCM` then you can try `Code` given below:-

```
# Import all Important Libraries
import math

# User input for Variable 'a' and 'b'
a = int(input("Enter Number 1:- "))
b = int(input("Enter Number 2:- "))

# Calculate 'GCD' of 'a' and 'b'
gcd = math.gcd(a, b)

# Calculate 'LCM' Using 'GCD'
lcm = (a*b)//gcd

# Print Result
print("GCD of 'a' and 'b' is:- ", gcd, "\nLCM of 'a' and 'b' is:- ", lcm)
```

```
# Output of Above Code:-
Enter Number 1:- 12
Enter Number 2:- 48
GCD of 'a' and 'b' is:-  12 
LCM of 'a' and 'b' is:-  48
```